# How does Google App Engine Autoscaling work?

Tags: google-app-engine, autoscaling, quota

This question is about Google App Engine quotas and instances.

I deployed a GAE app without specifying any specific scaling algo. From their docs, it seems like the default is auto-scaling.

So when do they scale the app to another instance, i.e. when exactly does a new instance spawn? What request/s causes the second instance to get started and traffic to be split?

Comment: do more research before assuming you are being ripped off. not funny. and very well explained in their docs.

Comment: And yet there is no answer to how many requests/s each instance class can serve before a new instance is spawned. Of course what their docs explain is logical: the instance serves requests until it no longer can serve them, and then the new requests are sent to a new spun instance. But don't you think providing a number to that will help? Their docs are huge, so forgive me if I missed something, but I wouldn't have made any bold statements in my question had I found the answer after enough searching

Comment: As an example, this is what Heroku's docs say about dynos: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos-and-requests. At least the user knows they're good up until about 1000 requests a second (of course taking into account their latency).

Answer (score 10):

Actually it is fairly well explained.

From [Scaling dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances):

> The App Engine scheduler decides whether to serve each new request
>   with an existing instance (either one that is idle or accepts
>   concurrent requests), put the request in a pending request queue, or
>   start a new instance for that request. The decision takes into account
>   the number of available instances, how quickly your application has
>   been serving requests (its latency), and how long it takes to spin up
>   a new instance.
>
> Each instance has its own queue for incoming requests. App Engine
>   monitors the number of requests waiting in each instance's queue. If
>   App Engine detects that queues for an application are getting too long
>   due to increased load, it automatically creates a new instance of the
>   application to handle that load.

It is possible to tune the parameters for autoscaling, see [Change auto scaling performance settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/managing-resources#change_auto_scaling_performance_settings) and [Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#scaling_elements)

If you really want to put a hard limit on the number of instances you'll probably have to use basic scaling with a `max_instances` config or manual scaling.